# Inheritance at the database table level, Jpa Joined strategy

Tags: database-design, inheritance, jpa, single-table-inheritance

I have been working with a data model for quite a while. I now believe the model is flawed but I am not sure how to improve it.

Basically my domain model is **a small ads website for parents seeking nannies/childminders and childminders seeking babies to look after**.

The domain model currently has an base Account class that is subclassed by two **ParentAccount** and **ChildminderAccount** classes. I also have base Advertisement class that is subclassed by three **ChildminderAdvertisement**, **ParentToParentAdvertisment** and **ParentToChildminderAdvertisement** classes.

Most of the attributes are common to subclasses and therefore located in the super class.

To list a few differences between subclasses:

- A ChildminderAccount may have a Curriculum/Resume attached to it but a ParentAccount may not.
- A ChildminderAccount is further refined by specifiying whether the Childminder(generic) is a Nanny(specific)/BabySitter(specific)/etc.

This means that the ChildminderAccount subclass has relationships to other tables that the ParentAccount subclass does not have.

The inheritance is currently implemented by the JPA layer using the Joined strategy (see JPA documentation: `@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)`) See diagram.[image]

I am facing a number of problems with the current design:

- I am having problems running operations common to base classes.
- I often find myself re-implementing methods for subclasses, I have too many DAOs.

As I said above, I am not sure how to improve the design: whether to forgo inheritance alltogether (db level) or whether to go for another inheritance strategy...

Any clue welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the reason the JPA guys made all that "inheritance strategy" stuff is to more closely emulate OO polymorphism when working with SQL Tables (via JPA entities). Are you sure you're taking advantage of this feature.

For example, if you want all Account type entries (no matter if they're actual ParentAccount or ChildminderAccount) you can do something like:

```
SELECT a FROM Account a WHERE ...."
```

Comment: Hello Andrei: then how do I deal with the differences at the java level?

Comment: Well, when you tell it "select a FROM Account a" it will effectivelly create an Account instance, so you only have access to those fields/methods. You can also do "select ParentAccount a from Account a" and here it will create ParentACcount instances so you can access those fields as well. You can also pass in "type" to tell it what kind of beans are you insterested in (from the entire inheritance chain contained in a table).

Comment: then I am not sure: do you advise jpa single table inheritance strategy or no jpa inheritance at all?